# the application has stopped, when i tried to clear all data

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i tried to clear all data from the table inside my database, it was successfull, but the only problems is, everytime i pressed the clear button, it does clear all data but after that the application shows it has stopped

[image: when i clicked the clear button]

which part did i go wrong? below is my coding from my database:

```
public boolean deleteRow(long id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        String where = data.UID + "=" + id;
        return db.delete(data.TABLE_NAME, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void DeleteAll(){

        Cursor c = readEntry();
        long id = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data.UID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) id));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
        return;
    }
```

and code from the other java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showbmi);
        initializeApp();
    }
    private void initializeApp(){

        weightinputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightid);
        heightinputid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightid);
        buttonBMI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBMI);
        BMIfinal= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMIfinal);
        BMIStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMIstatus);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        detail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bb);
        table_layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

        data  = new fitnessdatabase(this);
        BuildTable();
        bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                data.DeleteAll();
                new MyAsync().execute();
            }
        });



private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            table_layout.removeAllViews();

            PD = new ProgressDialog(Showbmi.this);
            PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            PD.setMessage("Loading...");
            PD.setCancelable(false);
            PD.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String weight = weightinputid.getText().toString();
            String bmi = BMIfinal.getText().toString();
            String status = BMIStatus.getText().toString();
            String date1 = mDateText.getText().toString();

            // inserting data
            data.open();
        //    sqlcon.insertData(firstname, lastname);
            long id = data.insertData(weight, bmi, status, date1);
            BuildTable();
            return null;
        }

        }
```

the error from the logcat as shown below:

```
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.adiehabs.fitnessku.Showbmi$MyAsync.doInBackground(Showbmi.java:188)
            at com.example.adiehabs.fitnessku.Showbmi$MyAsync.doInBackground(Showbmi.java:169)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: your naming "conventions" are anything but java...

Comment: Please post the logcat output.

Comment: i already editted my post together with the Logcat errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try `data.Open()` it hits an uninitialised variable as you've initalised it in a private void. Change it to public or put all that code into your created bundle. As the UI controls will also be null.

**edit** your updated with logcat confirms this. In the do in background.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.example.adiehabs.fitnessku.Showbmi$MyAsync.doInBackground(Showbmi.java:188)

`private void initializeApp(){`

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) id));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```

I would use:
Move the cursor to first and only move it if it's not gone past the last item.

```
  c.moveToFirst(); 
       while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) id));
           c.moveToNext();
        } 
    }
```

The other thing:

Have you declared these variables in your main scope `table_layout`,            `PD`?
The app not responding is often from a nullpointer exception.

Comment: my problem solved, i editted the do in background part and include the delete method in there, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Delete all table rows

```
public boolean deleteTable(){

    return mSQLiteDatabase.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, null) > 0;
}
```